# User control JQuery Issue

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, user-controls

I've created a user control which is very basic, It's a asp.net text box with JQuery autocomplete functionality attached. This is all defined in the aspx page not programatically.

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/jscript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/jscript" >


      $(function() {

    $(".tb").autocomplete({

        source: [ <%=GetAutoCompleteData%> ],

    });

});
  </script>


  <asp:TextBox ID="TBAUTO" class="tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
```

This works perfectly well when one control is on a page. However when i add another they both seem to have the same data which shouldn't be the case.

When i check what is rendered to the page it's as i expect but they both contain the same data when the auto complete functionality kicks in

This is what is rendered to the page 
[image: This is what is rendered to the page]

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you are chaining your autocomplete with a class by using $(".tb") which wil be a set of one or more dom elements. try using a # instead like below

```
    $(function() {      
        $("#<%= TBAUTO.ClientID %>").autocomplete({          
        source: [ <%=GetAutoCompleteData%> ],       
        });  
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If i put "#<%= TBAUTO.ClientID %>" it places a # in front of the ID which seems to look like they wouldn't match. The auto complete stopped working so i changed to "<%= TBAUTO.ClientID %>" but still no luck :(

Comment: In jquery you use a # prefix for selecting a dom element by id, you use a . prefix when selecting one or more items by element class, in this case you should use a #. Then you will only be chaining the autocomplete to one element at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As i was having no luck with the above solution and i knew that the 
 $(function() {

```
$(".tb").autocomplete({ 

    source: [ <%=GetAutoCompleteData%> ], 

});
```

worked i simply set the CssClass on page load to a given variable(DataFilter) in my code and just

$(function() {

```
$(".<%=DataFilter%>").autocomplete({

    source: [ <%=GetAutoCompleteData%> ],

});
```

Comment: Glad you got it working but if you are targeting one dom element you should use a # and id  instead

Comment: thanks for your help, Due to this only being a prtotype i'm not to fussed about this for now i'm just proving it can be done. Once i get the nod i will look in to getting it working correctly! CHeers for your help!